# Downloading a file from url in c# windows forms

Tags: c#

I have url like this

http://domainname.com/view/downloadfile?uname='ddd'&id=4

if we type the above url (not exactly the same ) in browser address bar it prompts open/save file dialog

my requirement is in button click  without open/save dialog i need to download the file to my local disk location

Actually am working with webbrowser control .button is outside the webbrowser control

Comment: Do you actually need the web-browser? Because you can download the file without it. Do you need your download code to somehow incorporate the web-browser?

Comment: actually there is a link for download in one site. what my requirement is without clicking that link by clicking a button outside the webbrowser it should be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) method. Or if you don't want to save the file on the disk but manipulate it in memory you could use the [WebClient.DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) method.

Comment: webclient.downloadfile is retrieving html page but i want the file to be downloaded

Comment: @suresh, in this case you need to point to the actual url that will return the file.

Comment: ,but i dont know which file is going to be downloded.because am giving just url which in turn returns file as open/save dialog i need this

Comment: @suresh, if you don't know you cannot download a file.

Comment: darin one thing i can say that all are word documents