# store images from links in csv file c#

Tags: c#, image, csv

I have a CSV file which I am importing using C# and the WSI service on our server.

The file contains url's for images e.g. `http://www.website.com/345366.png` and `http://www.website.com/125_dfg676.png` etc.

How can I store the image files from reading in the CSV col 7 and 8 of the CSV contain the image urls?

Comment: All the CSV and the WSI information is irrelevant. all you need to know is how to d/l the inage givan its URL. The link Dutzu post is good for that.

Comment: Reading CSV files (using LINQ):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/c-net-reading-csv-file

Save an image from URL:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110246/how-do-i-programatically-save-an-image-from-a-url

Answer (score 1):

You just need to download the files with a simple call.

You will find a lot of answers on stack. Here is one that is exactly what you need:

[Downloading a file from url in c# windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734305/downloading-a-file-from-url-in-c-sharp-windows-forms)

Comment: How is that exactly what I need this guy is trying to download an image via a button I have a csv with urls I want to store the images to a local folder?

Comment: @user1620523 yeah, so all you need to do is actually to write code that deserialises the csv and then with the urls take the answer that i linked to and use that approach to download the images locally. What were you expecting? The code written for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and no I was not expecting someone to write the code